# Can SignalR group be shared between different hubs?

Tags: signalr

After finding [this update](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1039) around communicating with groups, it appears that a group is keyed off the hub name. If this is correct (please let me know if I'm mistaken) is there any way for a hub to access another hub's group or better yet to have some kind of global group?

My problem is that I have one hub that adds the client to a group:

```
public class GameService : Hub, IGameService
...
public void CreateNewGame(CreateGameDto game)
    {
        game.Creator = UserRepo.GetUser(Context.ConnectionId);
        var newGame = GameRepo.CreateNewGame(game);
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, newGame.GameId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        Clients.Caller.JoinedGame(newGame);
    }
```

and another hub entirely needs to broadcast to that group:

```
    public class MessagingService : Hub , IMessageService
    ...
        public void AddMessage(MessageDto message)
    {
        message.User = UserRepo.GetUser(Context.ConnectionId);
        MessageRepo.AddMessage(message);
        Clients.Group(message.User.GameId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            .ReceivedMessage(message);
    }
```

As of right now, the client is never receiving this broadcast.

**Edited to add the client code.**
Here is the client side signalr setup, I've created a framework that allows me to use the service interface with a Castle Dynamic Proxy so that I'm not calling services and methods by string name.

```
public abstract class BaseClientProxy<TServer,TClient>
{
    public  TServer ServiceProxy;

    protected BaseClientProxy(HubConnection conn)
    {
        ServiceProxy = CreateProxy(conn);
    }

    private ProxyGenerator _generator;
    protected IHubProxy Proxy;
    protected TClient Receiver;

    protected TServer CreateProxy(HubConnection conn)
    {
        Proxy = conn.CreateHubProxy<TServer>();

        _generator = new ProxyGenerator();

        return (TServer)_generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget(typeof(TServer), new HubProxyInterceptor(Proxy));
    }

    public void SetReceiver(TClient receiver)
    {
        Receiver = (TClient)_generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(typeof(TClient), receiver);
        RegisterEvents();
    }

    protected void RegisterEvents()
    {
        Action<MethodInfo> regAction = RegisterEvent<object>;
        var methods =
            typeof (TClient).GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (var methodInfo in methods)
        {
            var locInfo = methodInfo;
            if (locInfo.GetParameters().Length > 0)
            {
                var regMethod = typeof(BaseClientProxy<TServer, TClient>).GetMethodExt(regAction.Method.Name, typeof(MethodInfo));
                var genAction = regMethod.MakeGenericMethod(locInfo.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType);
                genAction.Invoke(null, new object[] { locInfo });
            }
            else
            {
                Proxy.On(locInfo.Name, () =>locInfo.Invoke(Receiver, null));
            }
        }
    }

    protected void RegisterEvent<TDto>(MethodInfo method)
    {
        Proxy.On<TDto>(method.Name, x => method.Invoke(Receiver, new object[] {x}));
    }
}

public class HubProxyInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    protected IHubProxy Proxy;

    public HubProxyInterceptor(IHubProxy proxy) 
    {
        Proxy = proxy;
    }

    protected async void Invoke<TDto>(string methodName, TDto dto)
    {
        await Proxy.Invoke(methodName, dto);
    }

    protected async void Invoke(string methodName)
    {
        await Proxy.Invoke(methodName);
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        if (invocation.Arguments.Length > 0)
        {
            Invoke(invocation.Method.Name, invocation.Arguments[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            Invoke(invocation.Method.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Theses snippets are from a singleton class that establishes the connection and registers the services in a windsor container.

```
private SignalRManager()
    {
        var settings = Settings.GetSettings<IClientSettings>(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings);

        Connection = new HubConnection(settings.SignalRServerUri);

        ioc = new WindsorContainer();
        ioc.Register(
            Component.For<BaseClientProxy<IUserService, IUserClient>>().Instance(new UserServiceProxy(Connection)),
            Component.For<BaseClientProxy<IDrawingService, IDrawingClient>>().Instance(new DrawingServiceProxy(Connection)),
            Component.For<BaseClientProxy<IMessageService, IMessageClient>>().Instance(new MessageServiceProxy(Connection)),
            Component.For<BaseClientProxy<IScoreBoardService, IScoreBoardClient>>().Instance(new ScoreBoardServiceProxy(Connection)),
            Component.For< BaseClientProxy<IGameService,IGameClient>>().Instance(new GameServiceProxy(Connection)));
        Connection.Start().Wait();
    }
   public TClient GetService<TClient,TReceiver>(TReceiver receiver) where TClient : IService
    {
        var proxy = ioc.Resolve<BaseClientProxy<TClient, TReceiver>>();
        proxy.SetReceiver(receiver);
        return proxy.ServiceProxy;
    }
```

In this code the HubProxyInterceptor is responsible for making all calls to the server.

And the RegisterEvents method within the BaseClientProxy is responsible for wiring up the calls from the server to the client.  The TServer and TClient type parameters are 2 different but similar interfaces, TServer will be implemented by the Hub class on the server side and TClient is implemented by my WPF view model which is what is passed in in the call to SetReceiver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [GetHubContext](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub) in MessagingService.AddMessage to send messages to another Hub's groups.

```cs
public void AddMessage(MessageDto message)
{
    IHubContext gameContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<GameService>();

    message.User = UserRepo.GetUser(Context.ConnectionId);
    MessageRepo.AddMessage(message);

    gameContext.Clients.Group(message.User.GameId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        .ReceivedMessage(message);
}
```

You can store the `gameContext` in a field if you don't want to recreate it on every call to AddMessage.

Comment: This did not work either, does it matter at all that I'm using a self host configuration? The server is a console app and my only client right now is a WPF app.

Comment: Ok so in the GameService, I tried pulling out the MessageService context and adding to the group there and that worked, which is fine but that just means I will need to do the same for the other services as well which will be more code than if I could just use the GameService context. Any thoughts as to why it worked one way but not the other?

Comment: I would have to see your client code. Obviously, what I suggested should work. Perhaps your clients aren't properly subscribed to the GameService hub when you start the SignalR connection.

Comment: I have added the client side code that handles wiring up the connections to the hub, hopefully its clear.

Comment: You still haven't added the code that calls HubConnection.Start. You need to create your two HubProxy objects (one for both your GameService and your MessagingService) from the same HubConnection *before* you call HubConnection.Start or else you won't receive messages from those hubs. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#proxy

Comment: oops my bad,  I've added the constructor for my singleton class that manages that.